# B Tree and B+Tree Index diferencies

Tags: database, data-structures, b-tree, b-tree-index

I'm studying B+ Tree and B Tree and I would like to understand two things about it, if someone can clarify it to me I would appreciate it:

1. Why can I store more search keys on an B+ Tree Index? My guess would be that the reason is because the nodes of an B+ Tree point
   out to sub-trees instead of data.
2. Is there any type of comparison of data that will not work with an
   B+ Tree index or can I use all of them (=, >=, !=, <,<>...) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your questions completely (maybe that's why someone gave you negative vote), but I will give a try.

> A B+ tree can be viewed as a B-tree in which each node contains only keys (not key-value pairs), and to which an additional level is added at the bottom with linked leaves.

1. From this Wikipedia quote, it follows that the organization of keys/values is different, but I do not deduce that either B or B+ can store more keys than the other.
2. If you are asking if any type of data which has comparaison operators can be used as the key - the answer is yes.